# How to limit the number of connections to a socket?

Tags: python, sockets, select, client-server

From my understanding meaning of this code:

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 45671
server_socket.bind(("localhost", port))
server_socket.listen(2) #focus on this line
```

Is that only two clients can make a connection with the socket_server.

However, I can connect more than two clients.

Part of the client's code:

```
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 45671
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_sock.connect(ADDR)
```

*Server works with select library, in my opinion it's not the problem...

How can I limit the number of clients' connections to a server?

Comment: [`listen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen) seems clearly documented: *it specifies the number of unaccepted connections that the system will allow before refusing new connections*. If you want to limit the number of simultaneous connections, you can keep a count of the number of currently open connections and take any of several actions depending on your needs: you can simply stop `accept()`-ing any more connections once your limit is reached; you can also close the server socket entirely. Depends on what behavior you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your question's comments, `listen()` arguments serve a slightly different purpose.

You have to manage your connections on your own.
One example might be:

```py
import socket
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 8331        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

connections = []
MAX_CONNECTIONS = 2

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()

    logger.info(f"Starting server on {HOST}: {PORT} ...")

    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        if len(connections) >= MAX_CONNECTIONS:
            conn.sendall(f"Connection overflow. Max amount is {MAX_CONNECTIONS}".encode())
            continue

        connections.append((conn, addr))

        logger.info(f"Client connected: {addr}")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

Still, you have to write cleanup logic so that your `connections` array won't hold closed connections.
And also, you have to introduce some sort of asynchronous processing of these connections, because in this approach, only one active connection can be processed at a time.